# number of ways to distribute $60$ indistinguishable chocolates and $60$ indistinguishable toffees among $100$ different people

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, combinations

**question:** (i) Find the number of ways to distribute $60$ chocolates(all chocolates are indistinguishable) and $60$ toffees (all toffees are indistinguishable) among $100$ students such that each student get at least one of any kind (no student remains empty handed).

(ii) Find the number of ways to distribute $2$ chocolate and $2$ toffees among $3$ persons such that each person get atleast one of any kind (no person remains empty handed).

**my attempt**: I thought both parts of question are of same type and I proceeded as follows :

(i) First i selected $60$ students in $^{120}C_ {60}$ ways then , I distributed 60 chocolates among them in $1$ way (such  that each student get $1$ chocolate) and then, I distributed rest $60$ toffees among $40$ students in $^{59} C _{39}$ ways,and finally multiplied these two i.e, $[1\times  ^{59} C _{39}]$ ways

(ii)In second part of the  question first I selected $2$ persons in  $^{3} C _{2}$ ways gave each of them  $1$ chocolate in $1$ way, and then I gave $2$ toffees to $3rd$ person in $1$ way, and then again.  It is also  possible that I only give $1$ toffee to the $3rd$ person and distribute 1 remaining toffee among $2$ persons (to whom I have given chocolates) in $2$ ways thus getting $^{3}C_{2}.(1+2)=9$ ways ...but I think somewhere I'm doing something wrong in both (i), (ii), so please help .

I'm having difficulty in these type of questions. I am unable to understand if order of  objects (which we are going to distribute) will matter or not.

Comment: You should easily be able to see that you're missing possibilities. What if the chocolates are only distributed among 40 students? Why are you only giving toffee *or* chocolate to each student? Etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second question is simpler, so let's start there.

**Background:**  The number of ways of distributing $k$ indistinguishable objects into $n$ distinguishable containers is the number of solutions of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_n = k$$
in the nonnegative integers.  A particular solution corresponds to the placement of $n - 1$ addition signs in a row of $k$ ones.  For instance, if $n = 4$ and $k = 10$, then
$$1 1 1 + 1 1 + 1 + 1 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 3$, $x_2 = 2$, $x_3 = 1$, $x_4 = 4$, while 
$$1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 + 1 1 + $$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 5$, $x_2 = 3$, $x_3 = 2$, $x_4 = 0$. 
Therefore, the number of solutions of the equation $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_n = k$ in the nonnegative integers is the number of ways we can select which $n - 1$ of the $k + n - 1$ positions required for $k$ ones and $n - 1$ addition signs will be filled with addition signs, which is 
$$\binom{k + n - 1}{n - 1}$$

> Find the number of ways of distributing two indistinguishable chocolates and two indistinguishable toffees to three people so that each person receives at least one sweet.

We use the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Let $c_k$ be the number of chocolates received by the $k$th person.  Then 
$$c_1 + c_2 + c_3 = 2 \tag{1}$$
Equation 1 is an equation in the nonnegative integers.   The number of solutions of equation 1 is 
$$\binom{4}{2}$$
By symmetry, there are also $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to distribute the two toffees to three people.

Hence, there are 
$$\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}$$
ways to distribute two indistinguishable chocolates and two indistinguishable toffees to three people.  From these, we must subtract those distributions in which fewer than three people receive a sweet.

There are $\binom{3}{1}$ ways to choose a person who does not receive a sweet.
Suppose the unlucky person is the third person.  Then the number of ways we can distribute the chocolates to the other two people is the number of solutions of the equation
$$c_1 + c_2 = 2 \tag{2}$$
in the nonnegative integers.  Equation 2 is an equation in the nonnegative integers with $$\binom{2 + 1}{1} = \binom{3}{1}$$ solutions.  By symmetry, there are also $\binom{3}{1}$ ways to distribute the toffees to two people.

Therefore, the number of ways to distribute the sweets if one person is excluded is 
$$\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}$$

However, if we subtract this amount from the total, we will have subtracted those cases in which two people do not receive a sweet twice, once for each way of designating one of those people as the person who does not receive a sweet.  We only want to subtract those cases once, so we must add them back.

There are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways to exclude two people from receiving a sweet and only one way to distribute all the sweets to the remaining person.

Hence, the number of ways of distributing two indistinguishable chocolates and two indistinguishable toffees to three people so that each person receives at least one sweet is 
$$\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2} - \binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1}\binom{3}{1} + \binom{3}{2}\binom{2}{0}\binom{2}{0} = 36 - 27 + 3 = 12$$
a result which you can check by listing the possible cases.

> Find the number of ways of distributing $60$ indistinguishable chocolates and $60$ indistinguishable toffees to $100$ people so that each person receives at least one sweet.

The number of ways the chocolates could be distributed is the number of solutions of the equation 
$$c_1 + c_2 + c_3 + \cdots + c_{100} = 60 \tag{3}$$
in the nonnegative integers, which is 
$$\binom{60 + 100 - 1}{100 - 1} = \binom{159}{99}$$
By symmetry, there are also $\binom{159}{99}$ ways to distribute the toffees to $100$ people.  Hence, the number of ways the sweets can be distributed without restriction is 
$$\binom{159}{99}\binom{159}{99}$$
From these, we must subtract those distributions in which fewer than $100$ people receive a sweet.

There are $\binom{100}{j}$ ways to exclude $j$ people from receiving a sweet, which leaves us with $60$ chocolates and $60$ toffees to distribute to the remaining $100 - j$ people.  The number of ways of distributing the chocolates to the remaining $100 - j$ people is the number of solutions of the equation $$c_1 + c_2 + c_3 + \cdots + c_{100 - j} = 60$$
which is 
$$\binom{60 + 100 - j - 1}{100 - j - 1} = \binom{159 - j}{99 - j}$$
By symmetry, this is also the number of ways of distributing $100$ toffees to the remaining $100 - j$ people.  Hence, the number of distributions of sweets in which $j$ people are excluded from receiving a sweet is 
$$\binom{100}{j}\binom{159 - j}{99 - j}\binom{159 - j}{99 - j}$$
Thus, by the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, the number of ways the sweets can be distributed so that each person receives a sweet is 
$$\sum_{j = 0}^{100} (-1)^j\binom{100}{j}\binom{159 - j}{99 - j}\binom{159 - j}{99 - j}$$

Comment: Distributing two indistinguishable chocolates and two indistinguishable toffees to three people so that each person receives at least one sweet:  Observe that we can either give two chocolates to one person, who can be selected in three ways, and a toffee to each of the other people or one chocolate each to two of the three people, who can be selected in $\binom{3}{2} = 3$ ways, a toffee to the third person, and then give the extra toffee to one of the three people.  Hence, there are $3 + 3 \cdot 3 = 12$ possible distributions in which each person receives at least one sweet.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Thanks for pointing out my careless error.

Comment: @ N.F.Taussig: There is a typo after your equation 3, just after this line "From  these we must subtract those distributions in which fewer than 100 people receive a sweet " .....it should be $^{100} C_{j}$ in place of $^{60} C_{j}$ to exclude $j$ people from receiving sweet which leaves us with $60$ chocolates (not $100$) and $60$ toffees (not $100$) to distribute among remaining  $100-j$ people .........rest is superb sir , very nice complementary counting.thank you for answering .

Comment: @veereshpandey  Good catch.  Thank you for alerting me to the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that exactly $r$ of the students obtain $\geq1$ chocolates. Then necessarily $40\leq r\leq 60$. In a second step the $100-r$ as yet empty handed students receive a single toffee, and finally the remaining $r-40$ toffees can be distributed arbitrarily among all $100$ students.

The $r$ students receiving some chocolate can be selected in ${100\choose r}$ ways. The $60$ chocolates can be distributed to the $r$ chosen students in ${59\choose r-1}$ ways (put the chocolates in a row, then choose $r-1$ of the $59$ spaces between adjacent chocolates to separate them into $r$ nonempty groups). The $r-40$ remaining toffees can be distributed in ${(r-40)+99\choose 99}$ ways among the $100$ students.

It follows that the total number of admissible allocations of the sweets is
$$\sum_{r=40}^{60}{100\choose r}{59\choose r-1}{r+59\choose 99}\ .$$
Mathematica gave the following number:
$$4\,795\,799\,978\,358\,112\,587\,506\,029\,039\,656\,655\,902\,255\,946\,708\,243\,707\,900\ .$$

Comment: wow very short and sweet answer...without complementary counting ..........thanks a lot sir

Comment: Christian Blatter has a knack for finding elegant solutions, no doubt evidence of a deep knowledge of the subject.  I have learned a lot by reading his solutions.